# How to access anonymous user account in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, users

I have followed the [MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) installation tutorial on Digital Ocean, and during the process of running `mysql_secure_installation` noticed the following:

> By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,
>   allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have
>   a user account created for them. This is intended only for
>   testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother.
>   You should remove them before moving into a production
>   environment.

Question is, how do I access this anonymous user account ?  I've installed the database server simply for course. The machine is on LAN, there's no critical data on it, so I understand in production removing anonymous user is desirable but on personal machine for  learning it'd be nice just have one simple account to practice `SELECTs` and `JOINS`.

Answer (score 1):

Have them login as `test` with no password.

To check the existence of such logins, *you* connect as `root` into the commandline mysql tool (or some other tool) and run

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test'@'localhost';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test'@'%';
```

The first will tell you if users can get in from the same machine.  The second will say whether you can get in from arbitrary other machines (assuming no network or firewall limitations).